# Sort subviews in view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my application, I have a view which, in a dynamic way, I'm adding images, for example, in the view of 900 wide, insert 3 images, 1 of 200 wide, another 350 and another 200, if we try to add a 400 does not fit, so we have these 3 images placed next to each other and in the end left over 150, as in the first picture. What I need is these 3 images are placed such that are ordered at the same distance from one another, being as in the second picture:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sum up the total width of the subviews, subtract that total from the width of the parent view. Divide this result by the number of subviews being displayed minus 1, that's your padding between them.

Comment: using good old springs and struts

Comment: Are you adding those images dynamically at runtime?

Comment: You also have to subtract room for the left and right (narrow) margins. And yes you can use auto layout if you want, or you can use struts and springs (which are easier)

Comment: I'm adding images dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is the left and right offset from the view borders:

```
double offset = 10.0;
```

This is the frame of the view:

```
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
```

Calculate the 3 positions:

The first one is simple because start immediately (after the offset obviously):

```
double firstViewPosX = offset;
```

The last one is simple because start immediately from the end minus the *width* of that view:

```
double thirdViewPosX = viewFrame.size.width - thirdView.frame.size.width - offset;
```

The center one need to **take the space in the middle**, **minus the width of this view** then **divided for 2** and **sum this offset from the end of the first view**:

```
double secondViewPosX = offset + firstView.size.width + (thirdViewPosX - offset - firstView.size.width - secondView.frame.size.width)/2.0;
```

To make the last more readable:

```
double endOfTheFirstViewX = offset + firstView.size.width;
double middleOffset = (thirdViewPosX - endOfTheFirstViewX - secondView.frame.size.width)/2.0;
double secondViewPosX = endOfTheFirstViewX + middleOffset;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the problem is that there will not always be 3 images, depending on the width of the image, may I put 4 or 5 pictures if they fit.

Comment: ok, the algorithm is more complex but you should give me some min and max offset..for example do you want a min offset from a view and the other? the offset from the border of the main view instead is fixed or views should be centred as more as possible ?

Comment: I need 10.0 in the left and 10.0 in the right and from one to the other